# Passing extra data to Backbone Collection fetch -- returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, express

Suppose I have this Backbone route called **index** that fetches a collection from the server:

```
var characters = new App.Collections.Characters();
    characters.fetch({
      success: function(data) {
        var homeView = new App.Views.Home({
          collection: new Backbone.Collection(data)
        });
        $('#content').html(homeView.render().el);
      }
    });
```

Pretty straightforward right? On fetch success, create a new view and populate it with data that was retrieved from the server.

This assumes I am passing an array of characters only. In Express 3.0:

```
res.send(characters.slice(counter, counter+2)); // array of 2 characters
```

Now if I were to include a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) in addition to the two characters and instead pass an object:

```
res.send({ nonce: randomString, characters: characters.slice(counter, counter+2);
```

I can no longer access neither characters nor nonce when I do:

```
  // the same fetch function from above
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.nonce);  // undefined
    console.log(data.characters); // undefined
  }
```

Is Backbone Collection doing something shady under the hood? Why can't I access my object properties from *collection fetch*'s success object that were passed from the server?

#### Update:

Here is the console output when I send a simple array to my collection as in the first case:
[image]

And here how it looks when I send the data as @matt2000 has suggested and then calling it in Backbone as `data.models[0].attributes.characters;`:

[image]

Comment: The best bet would be is to check the console for any errors. And then check the network request to see what the response look slike

Comment: The first argument of the `success` callback is simply the collection itself, not the data sent by the server.

Comment: @Loamhoof that makes sense then. What are my options to get that data sent by the server in addition to the collection?

Comment: @TwilightPonyInc. try with the `parse` method maybe. If you need to go deeper into the `response` object, you'll have to dig into the jQuery XHR methods I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone does a little magic under the hood. It is not the raw data served by the server that will be passed as the first argument to the `success` callback but the parsed collection ([Backbone doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)).

You can override the collection's default `parse` method in order to get the array from the server's response.

```
var Characters = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url : //REST access point
  parse : function( response ) {
     this.nonce = response.nonce;
     // Anything returned by this function will be used as the first argument to
     // construct the collection.
     return response.characters;
  }
});
```

You can now use the characters instance directly when fetched, you don't have to create a new collection with it's result.

```
var characters = new Characters();
characters.fetch({
  success: function( collection ) {
    var homeView = new App.Views.Home({
      collection: collection
    });
    $('#content').html(homeView.render().el);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This method has worked for me, so I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data passed to the success callback is expected to be an array of objects. I think what you mean to do is:

```
res.send([{ nonce: randomString, characters: characters.slice(counter, counter+2]);
```

and:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data[0].nonce);  // randomString
  console.log(data[0].characters); // count
}
```